# Git checkout 'virtual' branch

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-checkout

If I'm several commits ahead of a git branch(I assume my commits form a 'virtual' branch) and I checkout to the 'real' branch, will the changes done in the 'virtual' branch (my commits) be stored?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is no such thing as a virtual branch in Git. You can switch back to your branch at any time to continue on it.
Here's a good read on how to work with branches in Git: [Git Branching Basics](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). It's one of Git's best sides imo